# Is it possible for gcc to name mangle?

Tags: gcc, name-mangling

I had some code that wasn't working until I added `extern "C"` before the name of a function, even though I was compiling using gcc. The file's name did, however, end in ".cpp".

Is it possible for gcc to name mangle? Did it intelligently pick up the file extension ".cpp"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gcc` compiler driver looks at the file extension.  If it is `.cpp` (or `.cc`, `.C` and a few more), the file is compiled as a C++ file:

- [Compiling C++ Programs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html)